# How to search in a Datatable and show results in another table using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am working with [DataTables (Table plug-in for jQuery)](http://www.datatables.net/). I need to search in one datatable and show the result rows in another table.

If I use this example:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

// #myInput is a <input type="text"> element
$('#myInput').on( 'keyup', function () {
    table.search( this.value ).draw();
} );
```

The search results will immediately be shown in table. How can I get this result rows in a variable to show in other table (instead of calling draw function for the source table)?

Comment: could you replicate the same on jsfiddle,http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: There are some working samples [here](https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html).

Comment: if you create a jsfiddle then it will be easy to fix the issue